# When does strong duality fail in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

When does strong duality fail in linear programming? I have considered the case when both primal and dual solutions are infeasible, but then there are no optimal solutions at all.

Comment: Can I ask why you deleted this question?  For future reference, we normally prefer that you avoid deleting your question after you've received an answer -- that might be considered impolite to people who take the time to answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that might help others in the future.  Deleting your question prevents others from benefiting from the answer; people writing an answer might be hoping that others would also be able to benefit.  I realize this might not be obvious at first glance!

Answer (score 3):

The strong duality theorem of linear programming states that (quoted from "Algorithms" by S. Dasgupta, C. H. Papadimitriou, and U. V. Vazirani, 2006) "***If*** a linear program has a bounded optimum, ***then*** so does its dual, and the two optimum values coincide." Hence, it never fails.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good exercise - 5.23 - in [Boyd's book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) on Convex Optimization (the [solution](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf) might also help).

They prove that strong duality holds for the following LP and its dual **provided at least one of the problems is feasible**.
In other words, the only possible exception
to strong duality occurs when $p^*= \infty$ and $d^*
= − \infty$.

LP:

$\min c^Tx$

st $Ax=b$

DUAL:

$max −b^Tz$

st $ A^T z + c = 0$ and $ z \succeq0$